# cURL command works on linux but not windows

Tags: linux, windows, curl

Good Day All,
I've got a cURL command here

```
curl -X POST https://*.com/graph/api/v1/graphql -H 'content-type:application/json' -H 'Authorization:bearer *token*' -d '{"query": "{ assets(query: { searchTerm: \"hello-world-sys-app-v1\" ,type: \"app\"}) { groupId, assetId, version, type } }"}'
```

This runs as expected on linux and returns like this

```
{"data":{"assets":[{"groupId":"*","assetId":"hello-world-sys-app-v1","version":"1.0.15-D160-B167-PERF","type":"app"},{"groupId":"*","assetId":"hello-world-sys-app-v1","version":"1.0.15-D157-B115-DEV1","type":"app"}]}}
```

However when running on windows I get an error like this

```
The request's Content-Type is not supported. Expected:
application/jsoncurl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bearer
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dc411cee-c007-4955-ab45-87522b2713ad'
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 17
```

I've tried a few solutions i've read on here without luck
https://superuser.com/questions/1291352/curl-command-runs-in-linux-but-not-windows-2008

I've tried a few different combinations of single quotes and double quotes but just getting errors, I've tried using a data file too, but i get similar errors. I have a feeling it is a simple issue, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: This looks like a quoting issue. Enclose the whole URL in quotes, good practice to use all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working now on windows, Although I still don't know exactly why its working but I first replaced all the single quotes with double quotes and was still getting errors. but after adding three backslashes I'm able to get a proper response.

```
curl -X POST "https://*.com/graph/api/v1/graphql" -H "content-type:application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer *" -d "{\"query\": \"{ assets(query: { searchTerm: \\\"hello-world-sys-app-v1\\\" ,type: \\\"app\\\"}) { groupId, assetId, version, type } }\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered the same pain a few days ago, and on Windows the -d must be between double quotes so you've to escape those inside. Something like this (I didn't test it):

-d "{\"query\": \"{ assets(query: { searchTerm: \"hello-world-sys-app-v1\" ,type: \"app\"}) { groupId, assetId, version, type } }\"}"

Om Windows you have Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell which seems (and only seems) is more accurate. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like Git Bash on Windows you may be hitting the problem with forward slash translations.

See https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/issues/196